# When is valid to first evaluate a function in a point and then do the DIvergence than to first the divergence and then evaluate?

Tags: derivatives, divergence-operator

I have been having this doubt when applying the Divergence of a Electrical Potential evaluated in a point, and then doing the Divergence to get the Electric Field in that point. But is this valid? or I have to do the Divergence first and then evaluate?

Because when I do the first thing I get the correct result, but the process of which I get the solution is triggering me a little

Comment: Go back to beginning calculus. To calculate the derivative of $f$ at $a$, do you differentiate $f(a)$ or do you evaluate $f’(x)$ at $x=a$? By the way, the field is the *gradient* of the potential, not the divergence.

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/787321/2451